# How to set scroll for height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tried to set scroll for height if height greater then 300px.Initially height is 0.when append the content if height is greater then 300 px i want to show scroll for height.How to do it?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cj87b41s/12/

```
function appendContent(){   
$("#rightDiv").append("<p> Content <span class='red'>(Remove X)</span></p>"); 
} 

$(document).on('click', 'p span', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

CSS:

```
 .rightDiv {
    width:215px;  
    vertical-align:top;
    background: #aaa;
    overflow-y: auto;  
    height:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `overflow-y: scroll` and `max-height:` 300px

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/1d46sa8v/

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
function appendContent() {
  $(".rightDiv").append("<p> Content <span class='red'>(Remove X)</span></p>");
}

$(document).on('click', 'p span', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.rightDiv {
  width: 215px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #aaa;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rightDiv">

</div>

</br>
<button onclick="appendContent()">
Append
</button>
```

Comment: @PappaS Glad that i was able to help you. Cheers.